# Clinet doesn't stop sending messages even server is stopped

Tags: java, sockets

I am working on a Java client which has to send a heartbeat message periodically. I am using java.net.Socket for the work. My issue is even the server is stopped client goes on sending the messages without giving any exception.
I read various stackoverflow questions on this, but couldn't find the answer for my implementation. I read that only way to find the server is up is to try sending a message. But here I don't see a way to do this.
Here's how my class looks like.

```
public void process() {
    sendMessage(HEART_BEAT);
}

public void start(String serverAddress, int port) throws IOException {
    this.serverAddress = serverAddress;
    this.port = port;
    if (isConnected) {
        LOGGER.info("Already connected");
        return;
    }

    socket = new Socket(serverAddress, port);

    out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
}

private void sendMessage(String message) {
     out.print(message + END_OF_MESSAGE);
     out.println();
}
```

Here's how my main method looks like,

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
     Client client=new Client();
     client.start("127.0.0.1", 900);
     while(true) {
          client.process();
          Thread.sleep(2000);
     }
}
```

How to implement a way to identify when the server has stopped?

Comment: @ScaryWombat You mean `BufferedWriter`, surely? A `ByteArrayOutputStream` doesn't have anything to do with a socket.

Comment: @EJP, Yes you are right, I did not mean `ByteArrayOutputStream` - actually I was meaning to suggest that the OP writing directly to the `OutputStream`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `PrintWriter` may not throw any exception when wirting but that doesn't mean that it hasn't run on an error. The underlying `OutputStream` still throws an exception but it's **internally** caught and processed.
The original exception and information may be lost but the [`PrintWriter#checkError()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#checkError--) method does still provide a way to check if *something* went wrong.
My suggestion is, to add some lines of code to your `sendMessage` method:

```
private void sendMessage(String message) {
     out.print(message + END_OF_MESSAGE);
     out.println();
     if ( pw.checkError() )
     {
       LOG.log( Level.SEVERE, "An error occured while writing.");
       shutdown(); // <-- method with the shutdown logic (e.g. closing the socket).
     }
}
```

Note that the [`PrintWriter#checkError()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#checkError--) method also flushes the stream before checking if an error occured.

It may not be the most elegant solution but it get's the job done.

Answer (score -6):

Lose the `PrintWriter`. It swallows exceptions. Use a `BufferedWriter`, which doesn't. When you get an exception when sending, close the socket.